# rsync - How to exclude a folder when there are multiple sources?

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to backup multiple directories with rsync, using `--exclude` option.

I know that `--exclude` paths need to be relative to the source path, but what happens when there are multiple sources?

Let's say I want to backup `/home/user/source_a` and `/home/user/source_b`, but want to exclude `/home/user/source_a/something`.

When I write `--exclude=/something` will both `/home/user/source_a/something` and `/home/user/source_b/something` be excluded (if there's `/home/user/source_b/something`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obviously misunderstand your question - so my first version of my answer was expecting you want to exclude the 'something' directory in **both** sources. I that case the trailling slash on the sources was needed.

To exclude **only** /home/user/source_a/something (**not** /home/user/source_b/something) as refined in your comment, you have to go a level higher, so that rsync is aware of the different sources. Then your rsync command would look like this:

```
rsync -a --exclude=/source_a/something /home/user/source_a /home/user/source_b /target
```

Just by removing the trailing slash at the sources will transfer the source_a and source_b directories itself, too. Therefor it is now possible to exclude a path from a specific source.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I want to only `--exclude` `/home/user/source_a/something` (not `/home/user/source_b/something `), what should I do?